# VB.NET drawing multiple lines on a PictureBox without removing previous changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to draw multiple lines on a VB.NET `PictureBox` without deleting the previous changes. If I try to draw two lines on a `PictureBox` during different times with `e.graphics`, then it would delete previous lines/changes.

I'm using this code on a `PictureBox`'s `paint` event.

```
Public Class DrawLine

Dim point1X As Integer = 10
Dim point1Y As Integer = 10

Dim point2X As Integer = 50
Dim point2Y As Integer = 50

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim pt As New Point(point1X, point1Y)
    Dim pt1 As New Point(point2X, point2Y)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, pt, pt1)    
End Sub

End Class
```

This example perfectly draws a green line inside the `PictureBox`.

However, when I have a button that draws another line on the `PictureBox` after the form has already been painted, the previous line drawn disappears.

For example, if I have a function like this that draws another line

```
Private Function DrawAnotherLine(xPos1 As Integer, yPos1 As Integer, xPos2 As Integer, yPos2 As Integer)

point1X = xPos1
point1Y = yPos1

point2X = xPos2
point2Y = yPos2

PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Function
```

It deletes the first line drawn and only draws the second line. I want it draw the second line on top of the first line and not just delete the first line though, how would I do this?

(Note: I cannot include drawing the first line in the function, as this function will be used multiple times on top of the lines its already drawn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDI+ drawing is pretty simple:

1. Declare one or more fields to store the data that represents your drawing.
2. Handle the `Paint` event of the control you want to draw on.
3. In the event handler in step 2, get the data from the field(s) declared in step 1 and perform the drawing.
4. To change the drawing, modify the field(s) declared in step 1 and call `Invalidate` on the control.

If you want to be able to draw multiple lines then you first need a data structure that represents a single line and then somewhere to store multiple instances of that data structure. The most obvious way to do that is to define a class or structure that contains the data for a single line, e.g.

```vb
Public Class Line

    Public ReadOnly Property StartPoint As Point

    Public ReadOnly Property EndPoint As Point

    Public Sub New(startPoint As Point, endPoint As Point)
        Me.StartPoint = startPoint
        Me.EndPoint = endPoint
    End Sub

End Class
```

and to then declare a field that refers to a collection of that type:

```vb
Private lines As New List(Of Line)
```

Your `Paint` event handler then draws all the lines in the collection:

```vb
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    For Each line In lines
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.StartPoint, line.EndPoint)
    Next
End Sub
```

To draw a new line, you add a new `Line` object to the collection and `Invalidate` the control:

```vb
Private Sub AddNewLine(startPoint As Point, endPoint As Point)
    lines.Add(New Line(startPoint, endPoint))
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

How you get those points is up to you. You might record the location on a `MouseDown` event and then call `AddNewLine` on a `MouseUp` event or you might do something else entirely.

It is also preferable to specify the smallest area possible when calling `Invalidate`, but that's beyond the scope of this question.