# VB.NET shifting all points of a line along the X coordinate from a list

Tags: vb.net, list, line, gdi+

I have a function that draws lines from a list of points in a `VB.NET` function onto a `PictureBox`. Two points are added to a list and a line is drawn between all points added in a list. However, when a new point is added to the list, I would want to shift all previously drawn lines to be shifted to the left.

For example, if 2 different lines were drawn between `(9, 0) (9, 4)` and between `(10, 0) (10, 3)` respectively from a list, and a third line was added to a list `(10, 0) (10, 2)`, I would like to shift the first two lines like this:

`(9, 0), (9, 4)` to `(8, 0), (8, 4)`

`(10, 0), (10, 3)` to `(9, 0), (9, 3)`

This is an demostration of what I mean.

The green line is the first line drawn and the yellow is the second line drawn. In the second figure, a dark blue line is added and the first two lines drawn, yellow and green, are all shifted to the left.

[image: Lines]

I am using this code to attempt to draw these types of lines.

```
Public Class Line

    Public ReadOnly Property StartPoint As Point

    Public ReadOnly Property EndPoint As Point

    Public Sub New(startPoint As Point, endPoint As Point)
        Me.StartPoint = startPoint
        Me.EndPoint = endPoint
    End Sub

End Class
```

```
Public Class Form1
Private lines As New List(Of Line)

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    For Each line In lines
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.StartPoint, line.EndPoint)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewLine(length As Integer)

    Dim pictureBoxRightXPoint As Integer = 300 'the right most side of the PictureBox is the x coordinate of 300 (PictureBox has the x size of 300).

    For Each l As line In lines 'move all points of X in all previously drawn lines in the list to the left.
            l.StartPoint.X = l.StartPoint.X - 1
            l.EndPoint.X = l.EndPoint.X - 1

    Next
    lines.Add(New Line((pictureBoxRightXPoint, 0), (pictureBoxRightXPoint, length))
    PictureBox1.Invalidate() 'Refresh the PictureBox to redraw the lines.
End Sub

End Class
```

After I add this, I get the error of:

> Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment

when I try to subtract `1` from the X coordinate to shift all points already in the list to the left.

How can I fix this or draw one line in a `PictureBox` when shifting all previously drawn points to the left? (Note: there can be multiple lines already added in the list).

(Code to just draw and add lines to list is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66621165/14924603).

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this by drawing lines on a picturebox?  Think you might find you will have to clear the picturebox each time you add a line and redraw the entire thing again. On topic, is there a reason you've made the StartPoint and Endpoint properties readonly and worth noting that vb naming is case insensitive startPoint and StartPoint are the same thing

Comment: Yes. My main point is to only shift the numbers already in the list @Hursey

Comment: What happens if your start and end points are not read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to draw the image in which I believe you stated (in your example) at the end of the `PictureBox`, you could just position your `PictureBox` inside the right end of a `Panel` and draw your graphics/lines at the beginning of the `PictureBox`. To move all previously drawn graphics to the left, you could move the position of your `PictureBox`'s location inside your `Panel` left.

You can use your previous function to add a new line, but move your `PictureBox` and position its start at the end of a `Panel`. To add a new line, use this:

```
Dim xint As Integer = 1
```

```
Dim r As Random = New Random
xint = xint + 1
Dim Point1 As New Point(xint, r.Next(40, 79))
Dim point2 As New Point(xint, r.Next(80, 100))

AddNewLine(Point1, point2)
PictureBox1.Left -= 1 'Move the PictureBox Left

PictureBox1.Size = New Size(PictureBox2.Size.Width + 1, 269) 'Change its size to allow for continuous line drawing
```

You can replace the random `Y` length I used with an actual point that you manipulate. The Line drawing function you linked will work fine for this. To clarify, make sure to use this:

```
Private Sub AddNewLine(startPoint As Point, endPoint As Point)
    lines.Add(New Line(startPoint, endPoint))
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

And your `Paint` event should be this:

```
For Each line In lines
     e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.StartPoint, line.EndPoint)
Next
```